# QWeb Report - Add space at the beginning of field

Tags: html, css, odoo, odoo-10, qweb

I have the following QWeb PDF report code:

```xml
<div class="row black">
    <div t-field="o.name" class="label_code" style="padding: 1em; text-overflow: ellipsis;"/>
</div>
```

The `o.name` field is aligned to the left side of the container div. As `label_code` applies a background color to this `div` the result is that the text lacks space in the left.

How can I add an empty space character before `o.name`?

Here is an image of the issue:

[image: The text inside the div -the black box- is aligned to the left side of the div]

this is the result using code   before the div as mentioned by Pranjal in his answer:

```xml
<div class="row black">
    &#160;<div t-field="o.name" class="label_code" style="padding: 1em; text-overflow: ellipsis;"/>
</div>
```

[image: Same printing adding the code mentioned by Pranjal Gami]

Comment: What do you mean by that? Can you show a screenshot? I think what you want to achieve can be done with the `padding`

Comment: @ChesuCR find attached screenshot, also note that padding has been used in the div.

Answer (score 1):

Use the padding in the parent div

```
<div class="row black" style="padding-left: 15px;">
    <span t-field="o.name" class="label_code" style="padding: 1em; text-overflow: ellipsis;"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this snippet before field  tag.

```
&#160;
<div t-field="o.name" class="label_code" style="padding: 1em; text-overflow: ellipsis;"/>
```

Comment: unfortunatelly this did not work, see my edited post for further details